# Create a file in a directory using Perl

Tags: perl, createfile

How can I create a new file, in which I intend to write in a existing directory using open() in Perl?

I tried like this:

```
my $existingdir = './mydirectory';

open my $fileHandle, ">>", "$existingdir/filetocreate.txt" or die "Can't open '$existingdir/filetocreate.txt'\n";
```

But it won't work.

Comment: Instead of "Can't open ..." say "Can't open ...: $!" to know the exact reason for error. Either ./mydirectory doesn't exist or you don't have write perms.

Comment: That works fine if `mydirectory` exists in the current working directory and you have permission to create in it.

Comment: Yes, this code works fine for me.  Another thing to check: are you sure that Perl's current working directory is what you think it is? Check with CWD: http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
my $existingdir = './mydirectory';
mkdir $existingdir unless -d $existingdir; # Check if dir exists. If not create it.
open my $fileHandle, ">>", "$existingdir/filetocreate.txt" or die "Can't open '$existingdir/filetocreate.txt'\n";
print $fileHandle "FooBar!\n";
close $fileHandle;
```

This should work for you.

Comment: -1 the OP wants to create a file "in an existing directory".  This might make the script run without dying, but it doesn't diagnose and solve the actual problem.

Comment: Well, I see the answer was accepted.  While I think my point stands, I will remove my downvote, since you successfully read the OP's mind about what the real problem was!

Comment: Would be better to use File::Path's `mkpath` than `mkdir`

Answer (score 1):

```
my $FILE;

open($FILE, ">>File.txt")||die("Cannot open file:".$!);

close($FILE);
```

You may append directory location in place of File.txt.